# Remove the bootstrap CSS class name underline warning in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using `VS Code 1.5.2.1` version for developing an angular application. In my editor `bootstrap css class` shows underline warning. The example is given below. Can anyone suggest how to remove these warnings?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are using "HTML CSS Support" extension. This extension is causing that. You can disable it.